# Is it possible to have two types of objects in an array of mongoose schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, schema

I am building an e-commerce application and this is my orders schema.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    buyer: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "buyer",
        required: true
    },
    items: [{
        item: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
            ref: "item",
    },
    quantity: {
        type: Number,
        default: 1
    }}
    ],
    seller: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: "seller",
        required: true
    },
    location: {
        type: {
            type: "String",
            enum:['Point']
        },
        coordinates: {
            type: [Number],
            index: '2dsphere'
        }
    },
    sendAt:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    } 
});

const orderModel = mongoose.model("orders", orderSchema);
module.exports = orderModel;
```

**I want to have an array having item-reference-id and quantity.**
But with the above schema when i enter data, each item is acting as an another sub-document and having _id. [Query response image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN9Fl.png).

Comment: I have problem similar to yours, were you able to solve it?

Comment: order: [
    {
      _id: false,
      item: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "items",
        required: true,
      },
      quantity: { type: Number },
    },
  ],

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution:

```
    order: [
    {
      _id: false,
      item: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "items",
        required: true,
      },
      quantity: { type: Number },
    },
  ],
```

`_id: false` will stop the subdocument from creating another id for the subdocument.